# Installing vim-fugitive on windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, windows-7

I'm a vim newbie, trying to install vim-fugitive on windows 7. I followed the instructions [on the script's github site](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)  without success.

If I run `:Git` I get the `Not an editor command :Git` error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you installed `pathogen`? Can you run `:Helptags` (note the capital initial letter) successfully?

Comment: :Helptags do nothing, :Ve a/pat<Tab> works. I quess pathogen is installed.

Comment: Same problem here, also on Windows 7. GVim 7.4.  `:Helptags` gives no error but is silent, so I guess it's succesful. But `:Git` says `Not an editor command: Git` and it doesn't seem like vim-fugitive is working when I open a Git-controlled file.

Answer (score 0):

`fugitive` only defines it's functions when you are inside a `git` controlled folder, so you'll have to initialize git in that folder before loading one of the folder's files to vim.

Simply run `git init` in that folder, and than open any file in that folder with vim, and you should have all of `fugitive`'s commands working.

Comment: I tried in a git controlled folder, but i still get the "Not an editor command" error. Also :Helptags does nothing.

Comment: It's not enough to be in a git-controlled folder. You also have to open a file in the folder before the commands will work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, here is how I solved it.

1. Right click on "Computer" from the "Start Menu".
2. Click on "Advanced system settings".
3. Click on "Environment Variables".
4. Go down to the "Path" variable under "System variables".
5. Click on "Edit..." then add to the end of the "Variable value the location of your git bin directory, mine was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin".
6. Close out all vim sessions, and command prompts.  At this point you should be able to open a command prompt and type "git" and you should get a list of commands.  If that works your Fugitive commands should work as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you install [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/), and check the following box, fugitive should work out of the box just as on Mac or Linux.

[image]